# Prove or disprove that $U+W=V$ for a set of given conditions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ and $W$ be linear subspaces of an real vector space $V$. I'm asked to determine if $U + W = V$ for the following case:

$$V = \Bbb R^3, $$
$$U = \Big\{(x,y,z) : x,y,z \in \Bbb R, x = y\Big\},$$
$$W = \Big\{(x,y,z) : x,y,z \in \Bbb R, x = 0\Big\}.$$

What I came up with is:
$$ (a,a,b) + (0,c,d) = (\alpha,\beta,\gamma) $$
Which gave me:
$$a = \alpha $$
$$c + a = \beta $$
$$b + d = \gamma $$

Can I conclude from this that $U + W = V$ ?

I'm very new to this whole field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true, $\forall v\in V$ you can demonstrate that there exist a vector $w\in W$ and $u\in U$ such that $v=u+v$. In other words, from your last expression
$$a = \alpha\\
c + a = \beta \\
b + d = \gamma $$
it means that for any $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ you can find a solution (a set of $a,b,c,d$ such that the system of equations has at least one solution)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is an elementary way to show that you can produce anything in $\Bbb R^3$ as the sum of elements from $U$ and $W$. You can even simplify slightly by setting $d=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your set up is correct: you get that

$$a=\alpha\;,\;\;a+c=\beta\implies c=\beta-\alpha\;,\;\;\gamma=b+d$$

so for **any** $\;v:=(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in\Bbb R^3\;$ , choose

$$\begin{cases}u:=(\alpha,\alpha,\gamma)\in U\\{}\\w:=(0,\beta-\alpha,0)\in W\end{cases}\;\;\implies u+w=v\implies U+W=V=\Bbb R^3\;$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can conclude that. Notice that $U+ W$ contains all the vectors of the form
$$(a,a,b) + (0,c,d) = (a,a+c,b+d)\begin{array}[t]{l}= a\cdot(1,1,0) + c\cdot (0,1,0) + (b+d)\cdot(0,0,1)\\
 = \alpha\cdot \underbrace{(1,1,0)}_{\vec{e}_1} + \beta\cdot\underbrace{(0,1,0)}_{\vec{e}_2} + \gamma\cdot \underbrace{(0,0,1)}_{\vec{e}_3}, \quad \alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb R.
\end{array}$$
Also, $\vec{e}_1, \vec{e}_2, \vec{e}_3$ are linearly independent, which means they form a basis of $V = \mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can determine that
\begin{cases}
a=\alpha\\
b=\gamma-d\\
c=\beta-\alpha
\end{cases}
and $d$ is arbitrary, so you even get infinitely many solutions.

A different way is noting that $\dim U=\dim W=2$, whereas
$$
U\cap W=\{(x,y,z):x=y=0\}
$$
so $\dim U\cap W=1$ and so
$$
\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)=2+2-1=3
$$
that entails $U+W=\mathbb{R}^3$.